# Image is in use, access denied can not delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on one application which deals with images.

I have code for creating new image from byte array.

When i create some new images with same name as that of the old file names.

and tries to delete the old files

it gives me exception that file is in use, access denied.

I am not sure which process holding that image and how to release it.

Please help me..... deleting that file.

Comment: Posting some of your code would help to give a better idea of what is going on, and where the problem may lie.  To speculate - I would guess that you are opening the old images somewhere and not closing them before saving.  If this isn't happening directly in your code, you may want to look at Process Monitor to help determine what has the images open.

Comment: Sample code?  You are probably not closing one of the objects you are using to stream.  It's most likely the resource locking the file out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code, if you are not using it the same way.

```
using( FileStream stream = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
{
         image = Image.FromStream( stream );
}
```

Posting your own code, would help though!